# Rest API call working fine with wifi networks. But not working with mobile Data

Tags: android

I am using retrofit and volley both for the API. The login is working fine with wifi networks. But in mobile networks its showing invalid username and passwords.

Comment: Intercept your network call. do you see any difference?

Comment: no there is no difference. Actually the api is used is work different with different location. Like it is location based.

Comment: Possibly the endpoint server is running on the local?

Comment: @JayRyu raised a good point . check that

Comment: @JayRyu how to check that it is running on endpoint server or not